# ¿Cómo obtener el resultado?

Tags: java, wcf

Tengo un `servlet` que en el método `doPost` tiene el siguiente código:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException 
 {
 Integer input1=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("input1"));
 Integer input2=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("input2"));
 ICalculadoraProxy calService=new ICalculadoraProxy();
 Integer result=calService.getMultiplicacion(input1,input2);
 request.setAttribute("op", "El resultado es: "+result);
 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
 rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

Y también tengo un `jsp` llamado `index.jps` con el siguiente código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

hay unos detalles que debes corregir:
1. Muestra, por favor, cuál es la declaración del servlet. Solo estás mostrando el método doPost. Supongamos que diga

```
//...
@WebServlet(name = "MiServlet", urlPatterns = {"/MiServlet"})

//...
```

La ruta para acceder a este servlet será `/MiServlet`

2. En tu JSP, la etiqueta `<form>` debe tener `method='POST'` y en el atributo `action` debería ir la ruta del servlet creado. Si seguimos el punto anterior, debería decir algo así:

```
<form method='POST' action='MiServlet'>
```

3. Tu botón debe ser de tipo `submit`. Le has puesto de tipo `button`.

```
<input type='submit' value='Calcular' id='op'/>
```

Si no es `submit` por más que le hagas clic nunca hará el submit.